# MySQL - Derived table query not fetching data for nested Select query

Tags: mysql, derived-table

I have a quey which has growth rates over a period of time. I am trying to obtain the overall growth between two rows that I specify. Here is the SQL fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1756ca/2

```
select i1.Month, i1.Rate,  EXP(SUM(LOG(1+i2.Rate)))   InfRate 
from Inflation i1
inner join Inflation i2 on i1.Month >=i2.Month
group by i1.Month, i1.Rate
order by Month DESC
```

This seems to work correctly and I am able to get the growth rate for the entire Month range in the fiddle, however I am trying to use a derived table so that I can specify the Month period, like this, however it is not working

```
select i1.Month, i1.Rate,  EXP(SUM(LOG(1+i2.Rate)))   InfRate 
from (SELECT * FROM `Inflation` WHERE Month between '2020-01-01' and '2022-01-01') as DT
inner join Inflation i2 on i1.Month >=i2.Month
group by i1.Month, i1.Rate
order by Month DESC
```

I get the error #1054 - Unknown column 'i1.Month' in 'field list'

I am trying to use a derived table for the period between '2020-01-01' and '2022-01-01' or any other range that I specify, however it does not seem to be working for me. Any help will be appreciated.

The expected result is something like this, considering that only the period between '2020-01-01' and '2022-01-01' was queried

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13f818/1

There seems to be some problem with the fiddle, here is an updated one

https://dbfiddle.uk/TwQ7VWs2

[image]

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and some sample output.

Comment: Your fiddle links don't seem to be valid.

Comment: @Booboo Yes, even I am not able to access it now, nor am I able to create a new one on SQLFiddle. Here is another https://dbfiddle.uk/TwQ7VWs2

Comment: Thanks @RickJames. Can you please see this dbfiddle.uk/TwQ7VWs2

Comment: Do you want the inflation since the start of 2020?  And compute that for every month since then?  (Please phrase the goal is words like this.)

Comment: @RickJames, the goal is to obtain the inflation for the period I specify in WHERE Month between '2020-01-01' and '2022-01-01', so in this case, the inflation in 202-01-01 would begin at 1 (plus whatever the inflation is for that period, 0.00310833 in this case, so 1.00310833) and the end month would be 2022-01-01, my Excel calculation shows the inflation for this period as 1.113519. So it would be 1*(0.00310833+1)=1.003108, the next would be 1.003108*(0.00310833+1)=1.006226, 1.006226*(0.00310833+1)=1.009354, 1.01249, 1.01563 and so on...

Comment: @RickJames, added a screenshot from my Excel calculation to the original question, can you please review it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for "inflation *since the start of 2020*, you need to limit i2:

```
Select DT.Month, DT.Rate,  EXP(SUM(LOG(1+i2.Rate)))   InfRate 
from (SELECT * FROM `Inflation` WHERE Month between '2020-01-01' and '2022-06-01') as DT
inner join Inflation i2 on DT.Month >=i2.Month
where i2.Month >= '2020-01-01'   -- I added this
group by DT.Month, DT.Rate
order by Month DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a table named `i1` in your second example, yet you're querying values from it. I believe what you want is something like

```
select DT.Month, DT.Rate,  EXP(SUM(LOG(1+i2.Rate)))   InfRate 
from (SELECT * FROM `Inflation` WHERE Month between '2020-01-01' and '2022-01-01') as DT
inner join Inflation i2 on DT.Month >=i2.Month
group by DT.Month, DT.Rate
order by Month DESC
```

Which replaces your `i1` references with `DT`.

Comment: Hello @DrGodCarl, I noticted that the results remain the same even after I change Month between '2020-01-01' and '2022-01-01' to something else. Essentially, I want the starting month '2020-01-01' to be 1 and then the subsequent growth/inflation should use this as the reference. The InfRate for 2020-01-01 is 1.0015 and then when I change the reference month to 2020-01-01, it builds upon the original value and uses the value of 1.0192, I want this to be 1. Can you please advise on this?